# Civ 6 Owned (developed) resource not providing any luxuries at all?

Tags: civilization-6-gathering-storm

Okay, so I have 4 unique owned (so the tile is developed) luxuries and am only getting 12 amenities from 3 of the luxuries (4x3=12).  For some reason the cotton I own provides nothing at all and I have no idea why, any thoughts? I am not using any mods, but I am using both expansions. Oh, and I have 8 cities, all of which need amenities (amenities are all -1 or below).  (note: amber is not shown but gives 4 amenities as expected)
[image]

Answer (score 6):

Since you're playing with the expansions, the World Congress is a thing (it's added by Gathering Storm). One of the possible effects on which players can vote is "A specific luxury resource doesn't provide any amenities". You can check which World Congress effects are active (and for how long) by clicking on its UI icon.

Comment: This and the possibility that you're trading it away are the only things I can imagine happened that's causing the lack of amenity from a specific resource.

Comment: World Congress . . . You got it, thanks a ton!